# .net login controls uses windows authintication by default

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, authentication

I just developed an web app using VS 2010 framework 4 it contains login control on the default.aspx and login status in the master page everytime Irun the application It ogin using windows username and I can't even logoff any help 
here is the web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".edmx" type="System.Data.Entity.Design.AspNet.EntityDesignerBuildProvider"/>
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
```

and here is an image how it looks like
[image]

how can I prevent this behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, authentication uses Windows Auth by default. You want to use something else. You need to change the authentication mode to forms or whatever you plan on using.

```
<system.web>
   <!-- mode=[Windows|Forms|Passport|None] -->
   <authentication mode="Forms" />
</system.web>
```